# ForEach Loop Container Mapping Variable From SSIS Package Not Working In SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, mapping

I have a SSIS package that uses a ForEach Loop Container to enumerate Excel files in a dir. I also have a Task Flow that inserts data from those Excel files into SQL Server.

I'm trying to insert the file names into a column into the same table in SQL Server by using a mapping variable in my stored procedure.

I'm having trouble with my MappingVariable at the end of the script with red squigglies. The following is my stored procedure script.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_F_STG_v2]
    @Hrs float,
    @Type nvarchar(100),
    @SN nvarchar(100),
    @Op nvarchar(100),
    @[USER::CurrentFileName]  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [CRM_RC].[dbo].[F_StgTbl]([Hrs], [Type], [SN], [Op], [Report_Date])
    VALUES (@Hrs, @Type, @SN, @Op, @[USER::CurrentFileName])
END
```

The last `@[USER::CurrentFileName]` in the values block at the bottom of the script is the one giving me issues.

The following is the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Insert_F_STG_v2, Line 95
>   Incorrect syntax near 'USER::CurrentFileName'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a derived column to your data flow, and assign `User::CurrentFileName` to the new column, then include this new column in your column mapping.

In your stored procedure, change `@[USER::CurrentFileName]` to a proper SQL type such as `@filename nvarchar(255)`.

Suggestion: You could also do away with the stored procedure, and insert directly into the table (would be faster, since its bulk inserted) by using a SQL destination instead of Executing a procedure for every row.

Comment: I like your answer.  I would like to do away with the stored procedure and insert directly into the DB...May you please point me in the right direction to do this...Im having a horrible time trying to figure out how to use the mapping variable.

Comment: If I use the DerivedColumn Transformation, what do I use as the input? as I used a ForLoop Container to grab the file names?

Comment: I also agree you should be moving towards a `BULK INSERT` Strategy but don't necessarily have enough info to do a demo for you.

Comment: @Zane what info would be useful for you to provide and example?  I am an intern and just learning SSIS (2 months experience)

Comment: Screenshots of your package would probably be helpful. Here's an example of one I have done in the [past](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/ssis-validation-slow-oltp-olap-running-on-same-server).

Comment: I think you might of posted the wrong link @Zane.  The link was for OLAP

Comment: @Zane I put a derived column transformation after my Excel Source and solved the problem...However, I am getting truncation error for the derived column...checked all the relevant metadata and seems to be fine.  any suggestion on this?

Comment: @Jeff, what step in SSIS is throwing the truncation error?  How big is the User::CurrentFileName variable in comparison to the new derived column and the SQL column you're inserting into?  Also below you mention a script to parse the date from the filename... where is that located and when is it called?

Comment: @Zane I fixed the problem.  Although my metadata was all correct in my destination, I realized when drilling into the Derived Column transformation that the length property was set to 0. So I went into the advanced editor, expanded Derived Column Output, expanded output columns, drilled into my Derived Column common properties and changed the length in there.  I realized what the problem was when I got home.  Thanks for the Derived Column solution; did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`@[USER::CurrentFileName]` is not a valid parameter name, and you don't have datatype assigned to it. SQL Server is treating `[USER::CurrentFileName]` as a datatype and therefore failing.

In the end it appears you are trying to insert that value into `[Report_Date]` column. Which I'm not sure how Date and Filename would be compatible.

Comment: The FileName has the date in it....I've already wrote a script to trim the FileName for the date.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create as second Variable that parses the useful information out of your file name. In a separate variable parse the date from `@[USER::CurrentFileName]` then use that Variable in this proc. I would be more specific but I don't know how your file is named.

Comment: That only gives Month and Year do you not care what the day is?

Comment: the reports are monthly, so I don't care about the day